# Optimizing six nested loops

Tags: arrays, optimization, fortran

> This question is related too: [Integrals involving three spherical harmonics and powers of trigonometric functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2466217/539931) on [math.se]

I need to optimize a three time nested loop. The operation
within the final loop is basically:

- call a function `incr` with the loop-indices as argument (*l<sub>1</sub>, m<sub>1</sub>, l<sub>2</sub>, m<sub>2</sub>, l<sub>3</sub>, m<sub>3</sub>*)
- perform some extra operations
- increment a value `a` with some intermediate results (it's a bit more complex and there are more sums).

In my calculations I need to run this loop for a large about of different
k values (see the code below). The first step to optimizing the code I took was to create arrays once, in the beginning of the program, and then read those. This means that the functions do not have to be evaluate each time the nested loops execute. My `lmax` is somewhere between 20-60, I would like to make it as large as possible.

One of my advantages is that most of the values in the arrays will be zero. Which makes it possible to do this calculation without running out of memory. I have made it so the arrays only contain the non-zero values and then I have made a function that has a set of if-conditions to evaluate if the index should be iterated or not. The selection rules are
somewhat complicated, but not overly so.

The reasoning for doing it like this is that now the loop consists of reading N arrays sequentially and that should be rather fast. The trade of is that I need to evaluate a bunch of if-statements.

The following Fortran pseudo code shows how it is done in principle.

```
do l1 = 0,lmax       
   do m1 = -l1,l1
      do l2 = 0,lmax
         do m2 = -l2,l2
            do l3 = 0,lmax
               do m3 = -l3,l3
                  tmp1 = 0.0d0
                  j1 = incr(l1, m1, l2, m2, l3, m3,i1)
                  if(j1 .gt.i1) then 
                     i1=j1
                     tmp1 = array1(i1)
                  endif
                  .....
                  a = a + k1*tmp1 + k2*tmp2 ....
               end do
            end do
         end do             
      end do
   end do
end do
```

> **Question:** Does anyone see a way to improve this? Where am I wasting time and can I even hope to improve it?

I should note that I am running OpenMP on top of this. The different executions of the loops are independent and I can do them in parallel. The only thing they have to share are the arrays `array1`, `array2`, and so on.

Comment: *I have made it so the arrays only contain the non-zero values and then I have made a function that has a set of if-conditions to evaluate if the index should be iterated or not.* and you have tested that you have not, by this approach, shot yourself in the foot performance-wise ?

Comment: Yes, I have. The switch from evaluating the functions each time vs the if-s with the arrays gave me a speed up of around 16 times. Not as much as I had hoped, but maybe not unexpected since I have to calculate a few logical expressions.

Comment: It is very hard to argue about performance without having the actual code. Almost impossible I'd say. Performance is about details and we can't see them. Tests are often necessary and we can't perform them. To be able to perform tests we need a [mcve].

Comment: You want the full code, that could be a problem. It would include a 1GB table, or the code to generate it. It is also ran on some data I can not share, I could maybe create some fake data. That however would be another few GBs I think.

Comment: It can be a surrogate code. The then conclusions may not be fully applicable to the real one, you must count with that. But it must be compilable and testable.

Comment: I could be wrong here, but it looks like you are computing [3j-symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-j_symbol) or something related. My suggestion would be to write everything in two loops (one resembling `l1`, `l2` and `l3`, and use integer divisions to get the values, second one over the m-values). If my suspicion of the 3j-symbols is correct, you can use if conditions to cycle out the impossible cases.

Comment: Any solution here?

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be a good start. But more information is needed.
Essentially, rewrite the 6 loops as 2 loops. One over the L-values and one over the M-values. You can use integer arithmetic to reconstruct the original `(l1,l2,l3)` and `(m1,m2,m3)`.

```
lim = lmax+1
l_loop : DO l_idx = 0,lim**3-1
   l1 = l_idx/(lim*lim)
   l2 = MOD(l_idx,lim*lim)/lim
   l3 = MOD(MOD(l_idx,lim*lim),lim)
   ! implement quick return
   m_loop : DO m_idx = 0,(2*l1+1)*(2*l2+1)*(2*l3+1)-1
      m1 = m_idx / ((2*l2+1)*(2*l3+1)) - l1
      m2 = MOD(m_idx,(2*l2+1)*(2*l3+1))/(2*l3+1) - l2
      m3 = MOD(MOD(m_idx,(2*l2+1)*(2*l3+1)),(2*l3+1)) - l3
      ! implement quick return

      tmp1 = 0.0d0
      j1 = incr(l1, m1, l2, m2, l3, m3,i1)
      IF(j1 .GT.i1) THEN 
         i1=j1
         tmp1 = array1(i1)
      ENDIF
      ...
      a = a + k1*tmp1 + k2*tmp2 ...
   END DO m_loop
END DO l_loop
```

Comment: This was a good suggestion. I have implemented this and done some initial tests, the speed up seem to be around a factor of 1.5~5. Its a bit hard to tell exactly how much because I have not done a full test yet and I have made a few other changes. Some were necessary when rewriting the loops. I do not fully understand why this works, I thought that compilers and the nature of loops in fortran would be pretty good at optimizing this kind of loops. (I only returned to this project this week after working on other projects. PM me your name for acknowledgment in a possible future publication )

Comment: @HaakonA the trick is the quick return, by checking if you need to enter the second loop or not. In your original code you always go 6 levels deep, even if after the third or fourth level you already know nothing will happen. If we would know the combinations for the lm combinations we might be able to speed this up much more. Is this  3j related or related to spherical harmonics?

Comment: Here is the thing, all of the quick return I have taken care of in advance. There are very few, if any cases, where the inner loop does not have to be run. So I have not implemented a return quick return yet. Still, I see a significant speedup. It is related to a problem I posted about in the math-part, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2466217/109986, a question I will soon post an answer too.

Comment: @HaakonA have a look at  Applied Mathematics Letters 12 (1999) 101-105 A Generalized Formula for the Integral of Three Associated Legendre Polynomials. This solves your math question

Comment: yes this is exactly what I found. I see you posted an answer to the math question, which sums up the basics of what I am implementing here.

Comment: @HaakonA Am I correct to understand that `array` is the table containing various results of the integral for various combinations of `l1, m1, l2, m2, l3, m3` and `incr` jumps to the correct position where you stored it? If so, what is `i1`?

Comment: A table for `l1,m1,l2,m2,l3,m3,n1,n2,n3,n4` (but yes). The rest is right yes.  For each iteration I have ~20 of those statements being executed.  So I have 20 arrays with the tabulated data. Array1 holds the values in the order I need to access them in the loop, the incr functions increases the index only when the value is non-zero. i1 then acts to make sure that the array is only read when it is appropriate, that is what the if-statement is about. The same is done for the other 20 arrays. I have done it this way to optimize the order in which the arrays are read by the processor.